# Regular expression works on browser but not in Node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have to match some strings from the given variables. Say I have variable

```
var x = 'elseif testing';
```

Now I want get value "testing" from this string. So wrote.

```
x.match(/^elseif(.*)/);
```

Late I realized sometimes I do get string:

```
var x = 'else if testing';
```

So I wrote expression to match:

```
x.match(/^else[\s+]if(.*)/);
```

This works well on browser but not in Node.js. Any reason why ?

Comment: Note that this doesn't "work well in browers" - try it, it behaves the same in browsers as in node.js - that is, it matches `else if` and `else  \t if` but not `elseif`. The `+` modifier means 1 or more. You want the `*` modifier which means 0 or more.

Comment: so, there is no difference between browser and node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without `double escapes` and `character class`:

```
x.match(/^else\s*if(.*)/i);
```

Also added `i` for case insensitive search.

Also note `[\s+]` will also match a literal `+` since inside `character class` `+` (and many other regex special characters) is considered a literal plus.

Answer (score 0):

If you're explicitly wanting to match only one or zero spaces, then:

```
x.match(/^else\s?if(.*)/i);
```